# VS 2015 Update 3 Remote Debugger download

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Im trying to download the remote tools for vs 2015 Update 3. 
However the Microsoft download keeps redirecting me to a page saying "Sorry, we couldn't find any downloads for you.".

Are there any other links i can use?

[image]

Comment: Check the msdn link, it has download links https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging

Comment: @bradbury9 No it still redirects me to my screenshot when i click on the download on your link. Can you go to the point where it gives you a download prompt and send me that URL?

Comment: click on the" join VS DEv Essentials" link and register for free for this project and now you get a lot of free downloads.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Perfect. Thanks. I had clicked that before but got another error about not having a subscription. I however failed to notice another button saying to join on the error page. Not the most intuitive by microsoft.

Comment: ok, I posted it as answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Microsoft moved nearly all programming related downloads to the free [Visual Studio Developer Essentials](https://www.visualstudio.com/dev-essentials/) Program.

After signin with your Microsoft Account, click on the [Join Visual Studio Developer Essentials](https://my.visualstudio.com/Benefits) link to register to the project.

Now you can find the [Remote Debugger](https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=remote%20tools%20visual%20studio%202015)

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Microsoft man. Link for that tool is dead.

Comment: I checked also and it didn't work.

Comment: @SeyedHosseinMirheydari what is not working? I just tested it and can find it easily.

Comment: @magicandre1981 You can follow [Remote Debugger](https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=remote%20tools%20visual%20studio%202015) then you see it can not be found.

Comment: The following link works at current point of time: [Remote Debugger Archive](https://zzz.buzz/notes/visual-studio-remote-debugger/)

Comment: @SeyedHosseinMirheydari I clicked your 1st link and it works fine.

Comment: @magicandre1981 That is a strange phenomena, I encounter with the screen that can be seen [from here](https://terabox.com/s/1Afb4_EnPjo66ggV0cTXGqA) when I clicked on 1st link in any browser

Comment: @SeyedHosseinMirheydari see [my picture it works fine](https://www.dropbox.com/s/a99wn4ilvqxl3nv/_remoteDebugVS2015.png?dl=0)

Comment: @magicandre1981 Have you bought Visual Studio from Microsoft?

Comment: @SeyedHosseinMirheydari no, this is my private account. Have you clicked the join link to register for free?

Comment: @magicandre1981 yes